# Merging list sharing a key in Groovy

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I'm new to Groovy and I'm trying to merge lists sharing a key, the ouput must be key, sub-list1, sub-list2 ...

```
["08_087C", 1 , 225]
["08_087C", 0 , 179]
// Out
["08_087C", [0 , 179], [1 , 225]]
```

The order of the sub-lists doesn't matter.

What would be the right way to do this, without "reinventing the wheel" ?

Comment: Lists don't have keys, they have elements. Are you talking about merging maps instead, where there is a key and a value, and values can be lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about "keys" in the context of a list, your result most
likely should be a Map, which makes later handling alot easier, if you want to
access your data by said key.  The following code, does exactly as you asked
for.

It groups your rows by the first element and puts them in a single row on that
key.  Since your example is sorted, but you failed to mention, your constraints
there, I assume you can live with the default sort order.

```
def data = [
    ["08_087C", 1, 225],
    ["08_087C", 0, 179],
]

assert data.groupBy{ 
    it.head() 
}.collect{ k, v -> 
    [k] + v*.tail().sort()
} == [["08_087C", [0, 179], [1, 225],]]
```

And here is the same code to create a Map instead.  The differences is the use of `collectEntries` instead of `collect`:

```
assert data.groupBy{ 
    it.head() 
}.collectEntries{ k, v -> 
    [k, v*.tail().sort()]
} == ["08_087C": [[0, 179], [1, 225],]]
```

Answer (score 0):

see this helps

```
def l1 = ["08_087C", 1 , 225]
def l2 =["08_087C", 0 , 179]
def out= [l1.intersect(l2), [l1.minus(l2)],[l2.minus(l1)]]
println out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the intersection property on list as below

```
List firstList = ​["08_087C", 1 , 225]
List secondList = ["08_087C", 0 , 179] 

//check if they have common element
def intersectElement = secondList.intersect(firstList) ? secondList.intersect(firstList)[0] : null
if(intersectElement){

    //build the final list
    List outputList = [intersectElement, firstList.minus(intersectElement),secondList.minus(intersectElement)] 
    println "outputList : " + outputList
}
```

Output:

```
outputList : ["08_087C", [1, 225], [0, 179]]
```